# How does Fetching | Loading json Data to a List<myClass> in Flutter Exactly work?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, async-await

How does that works in my case down below?

I tried many ways but i just could not figure it out.

Also, How to load a local json file and use it's keys:values as a class?

```
class Countries{
  int id;
  String name;

  Countries(this.id,this.name);

  static Future<List<Countries>> getJsonCountries() async {
    String apiUrl = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/keeguon/2310008/raw/bdc2ce1c1e3f28f9cab5b4393c7549f38361be4e/countries.json";
    http.Response resp = await http.get(apiUrl);
    return json.decode(resp.body);
  }

  static List<Countries> getCountries() {

        List<Countries> ls =  getJsonCountries() as List<Countries>; // Idk why this does not work ..
        return ls;
        // return <Countries>[ <-- this works fine ...
        //   Countries(1,'Morocco'),
        //   Countries(2,'France'),
        //   Countries(3,'USA'),
        //   Countries(4,'Tunisia'),
        // ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json file is not properly formatted. Strings should be wrapped in double quotes. This will immediately stop you from parsing the json in Dart/Flutter. Both the values and the keys need to be in double quotes to be parsed by Dart.

You can check it yourself by copy pasting your json in here and testing it: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/